# If my creature with deathtouch and 0 power blocks one of my opponent's creatures, does my opponent's creature die?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Deathtouch means that "any creature dealt damage by another creature with deathtouch is destroyed", but what if that creature with deathtouch is `0/1`? I suppose a better title would be 'does a creature with 0 power deal damage in combat?', but it seems like deathtouch is the most prominent case where this would come into play.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No. Deathtouch still requires that damage be dealt:

> 702.2b Any nonzero amount of combat damage assigned to a creature by a source with deathtouch
> is considered to be lethal damage, regardless of that creature’s toughness.

Here's the more general rule as well:

> 119.8. If a source would deal 0 damage, it does not deal damage at all. That means abilities that trigger
> on damage being dealt won’t trigger. It also means that replacement effects that would increase the
> damage dealt by that source, or would have that source deal that damage to a different object or
> player, have no event to replace, so they have no effect.

A corollary to all this is that a creature with deathtouch can only kill as many creature as it has points of damage to assign -- for instance, casting [Lure](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=226905) on your 2/2 [Acidic Slime](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Acidic%20Slime) doesn't let you wipe out your opponent's whole team, just two blockers.

Comment: Yup, but Lure on Cockatrice will kill everything that blocks it because it's not Death Touch.